# combining 2 tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is what I am looking to do but I have my doubts if its possible or not!

I have 2 tables, one is called `users` and the other is `answers`. I need to combine the results into a single statement, and order the table by `time`. the tricky part is that I have `time` on both tables and I need to take both `time` fields into account for ordering the results.

This is my unsuccessful attempt to come up with the query:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT id, username, first_name, last_name, time FROM users
UNION ALL
  SELECT id, answer, pid, uid, time FROM answers ) as AB
ORDER BY `AB.time`
```

**UPDATE**

I have come up with the following SQL Query:

```
 SELECT username AS user, '' as page , '' as content , time FROM users 
UNION ALL
  SELECT (SELECT username FROM users WHERE `id`=`uid`) AS user, pid AS page, answer AS content, time FROM answers 
ORDER BY `time` DESC
```

its what I am looking for but for some reason the `user` field in the second SELECT query is showing as `null`! any idea why?

Comment: mention the expected output in post and close it in once.

Comment: the problem is this part: " SELECT (SELECT username FROM users WHERE `id`=`uid`)"  for the second SELECT command, I would like a field to fetch username from users table using `uid` from `answers` table

Comment: `user` field is `NULL` because word `user` is reserved for `(SELECT username FROM users WHERE 'id'='uid') AS user` I guess. Change to e.g. theUser and check it out

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT id, username, first_name, last_name, time FROM users
UNION ALL
  SELECT id, answer, pid, uid, time FROM answers 
ORDER BY 'time`
```

solution to have different column name for each table

```
SELECT id         AS t1_id, 
       username   AS t1_username, 
       first_name AS t1_first_name, 
       last_name  AS t1_last_name, 
       NULL       ast2_id, 
       NULL       AS t2_answer, 
       NULL       AS t2_pid, 
       NULL       AS t2_uid, 
       time 
FROM   users 
UNION ALL 
SELECT NULL   AS t1_id, 
       NULL   AS t1_username, 
       NULL   AS t1_first_name, 
       NULL   AS t1_last_name, 
       id     ast2_id, 
       answer AS t2_answer, 
       pid    AS t2_pid, 
       uid    AS t2_uid, 
       time 
FROM   answers 
ORDER  BY time
```

Comment: thanks that works, but I am getting the results all mixed up, the field names for the second SELECT statement is the same as the first SELECT field names, is there anyway to customize the field names for the results?? also I am getting `[BLOB - 6B]` with `6B` being different in each result, why is that?

Comment: thanks :) ... I figured that out by myself, do you mind taking a look at the question again,I updated it again!

Comment: If you want to take both times to order results - `ORDER BY users.time, answers.time` (if users.time is higher priority).

Answer (score 1):

If users.id and answers.uid are supposed to be the same then this should work:

```
SELECT u.*, a.* FROM users AS u
    JOIN answers AS a ON a.uid = u.id
    ORDER BY a.time
```